# Where to keep text files in Android project in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, file

I am trying to find out, where should I keep text files in my Android project and how to refer their location in the code.

I kept my files under the main project directory and referred in the file as /sample.txt. but this did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would store it in the assets folder and reference it by using something like

`Activity.getAssets().open(sample.txt)`

Answer (score 0):

You should keep them in `/assets` dir. Access them later with [AssetManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html).